# I need two consecutive lowercases for a password requirement

Tags: python

I am having problems checking 2 consecutives lower cases in a string.

I have tried this:

```
def consecutivelowercases(input):
    checker = re.compile(r'([a-z][a-z])') 
    for char in input:          
        if re.search(checker, char):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

I expect the outputs to be :

- "TesT" gives `True`
- "TEST" gives `False`
- "test" gives `False`

Comment: What is your input? and what you getting in actual output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use a loop. Assuming 'input' is a string. then `for char in input:` is going to check each individual character against the compiled expression, which will fail, because your regular expression is 2 characters long.

```
def consecutivelowercases(input):
    checker = re.compile(r'([a-z][a-z])') 
    return bool(re.search(checker, input))
```

Comment: It does not work, if you make consecutivelowercases('test'), it returns True when it should return False. In the question is detailed **"test" gives False**

Comment: In that case there should be more detailed rules about what strings would pass the test. There is some ambiguity. Should the string contain only 2 consecutive lowercase letters and no more? Must the string contain at least one upper case letter? I think the phrasing of the question isn't clear enough to address this directly.

Answer (score 0):

iamchoosinganame did it by means of simpler form (good answer!). If you want to keep your structure:

```
def consecutivelowercases(input):
    checker = re.compile(r'([a-z][a-z])') 
    if checker.search(input):        
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

In addition, if you want to know where your regular expression find the first match, I would:

```
    def consecutivelowercases(input):
    checker = re.compile(r'([a-z][a-z])')
    a = checker.search(input)
    if a:
        print('first match: ' + a.group(1))
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```